# VB.NET MySQL - datatable returns blank row while db has no data

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to search a data in my `MySQL` table...

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim qry As String = "SELECT SUM(amt) FROM fee_payment WHERE roll_no='" + st_roll + "' AND course='" + c_id + "'"
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandText = qry

Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim dadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
dadapter.SelectCommand = cmd
dadapter.Fill(dt)
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        Dim t_paid = dr("SUM(amt)")
        TbDue.Text = tot_fees - t_paid
    End While
    dr.Close()
End If
```

Surprisingly the above `dt.Rows.Count` returns `1` while the table `fee_payment` has no data.

What should I do ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *nothing* surprising at all about the result.

An aggregation query with no `group by` *always* returns one row.  If all rows are filtered out, then most aggregation functions return `NULL`, although `COUNT()` and `COUNT(DISTINCT)` return `0`.

This is standard behavior and how all databases work.  It is actually quite a convenience under some circumstances.

EDIT:

If you wanted behavior where *no* rows are returned, just add a `group by`:

```
SELECT SUM(amt)
FROM fee_payment
WHERE roll_no = '" + st_roll + "' AND course = '" + c_id + "'
GROUP BY roll_no, course;
```